# Is "muli" a MIPS instruction? Where is it defined?

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

I have the following MIPS code (for swapping adjacent elements from an array) from a class slide:

```
muli $2, $5,4
add  $2, $4,$2
lw $15, 0($2)
lw $16, 4($2)
sw $16, 0($2)
sw $15, 4($2)
jr $31
```

This exact code will come up via google, so it must be a sort of standard example used in various colleges.

I understand all of it; in class I assumed "muli" was multiply immediate.    (Editor's note: multiply by a power of 2 is best done with a left shift like `sll $2, $5, 2`, never a multiply.  No compiler would ever emit this, and you'd only write this way by hand to dumb down the array indexing for this swap function.)

Now it appears "muli" is not a command at all (at least I don't see it on any of my references).

What am I missing?  I apologize if this is a dumb question but it is stumping me.

Comment: It might be a pseudo-instruction (like `li` and `move`) implemented by whatever MIPS assembler the person that wrote that example was using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the way, in case anyone else ever comes searching for this same question, I found something after a long search.

This is from an errata sheet for the previous edition of the textbook:

> > .
> >     .
> >     .
> >     12 There is no pseudoinstruction for MIPS with the mnemonic "muli" as listed in the middle of Figure 1.3.
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .

So...it's a typo in the book.  Mystery solved.  Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Your original MIPS code is a simple swap of adjacent values from an index `k` inside an array.  It implements this C:

```
swap(int v[] , int k)
{  
    int temp;
    temp = v[k];
    v[k] = v[k+1];
    v[k+1] = temp;
}
```

Your code is using the non-existent `muli` as an immediate multiply by 4, instead of `sll $2, $5, 2`, as part of array indexing for 4-byte words.

Explanation of Original MIPS code:

1. k = $5
2. Base address of v = $4
3. Address of v[k] = $4(base address of array v) + (sizeof
   integer)4*$5(index k)
4. (muli) $2 = 4*$5
5. (add) $2 = $4 + $2
6. (Now $2 stores address of v[k])

---

**Some other ISAs do have an immediate multiply, for example PowerPC.**
According to [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/assembler/idalangref_mulli_mlw_instrs.html) muli and mulli are same instructions on PowerPC/POWER.

```
muli RT, RA, SI            # PowerPC instruction, not MIPS
```

This instruction multiplies `RA` register source and the `SI` signed immediate, putting the result into `RT`, the target register.

Comment: That IBM link is of course for PowerPC, not MIPS!  PowerPC has many more opcodes, using more instruction bits for opcodes, vs. MIPS using lots of its coding space for 16-bit immediates.  (e.g.  PowerPC [`rlwinm reg, reg, imm, imm, imm`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/assembler/idalangref_rlwinm_rlinm_rtlwrdimm_instrs.html) is a fun rotate-and-mask instruction, useful for bitfield extracts or just masking with any bit-range.)